# Losing previous Record when we add new record in VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have problem that `Recordset.Addnew` is clearing the previous record in Access databse.

When I run the application, the test results will be updated to accessDB file.
But when it updates a new record, the previous test result records will be lost.

Please help me on this.

This is the code I am using,

```
TesterMainRS.Index = "DateTime" 
TesterMainRS.Seek "=", DateTime 

If Not TesterMainRS.NoMatch Then 
    TesterMainRS.Delete 
End If 

TesterMainRS.AddNew 
TesterMainRS![DateTime] = DateTime 
TesterMainRS![OrderNumber] = OrderNumber 

If DateDiff("s", PanelStart, PanelEnd) > 0 Then 
    TesterMainRS![PanelCycle] = DateDiff("s", PanelStart, PanelEnd) 
Else 
    TesterMainRS![PanelCycle] = 0 
End If 

TesterMainRS.Update
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more code or what exactly is the scenario of this, so we might be able to try and reproduce??

Comment: Hello paul..i am not sure where its exactlty happening.but i have method where the data will be append to database..please see below code.

Comment: TesterMainRS.Index = "DateTime"                 
    TesterMainRS.Seek "=", DateTime                 
    If Not TesterMainRS.NoMatch Then
        TesterMainRS.Delete 
    End If
    TesterMainRS.AddNew                        
    TesterMainRS![DateTime] = DateTime
    TesterMainRS![OrderNumber] = OrderNumber   
    If DateDiff("s", PanelStart, PanelEnd) > 0 Then
        TesterMainRS![PanelCycle] = DateDiff("s", PanelStart, PanelEnd)
    Else
      TesterMainRS![PanelCycle] = 0
    End If   
    TesterMainRS.Update

Comment: Please help me on this,...

Comment: you are deleting the record with TesterMainRS.Delete.